# Debugging node.js: "iron-node not recognized"

Tags: node.js, iron-node

I have node.js working fine on my Win10 machine, and now I'm trying to install iron-node. I've followed the instructions to run

`npm install iron-node -g;` and then `iron-node YOURFILE.js` but when I do I get:

`'iron-node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I can't find anything about how to resolve this, either in the official docs or via Google. Not even a whiff here on Stack Overflow. Ideas?

Comment: I recently upgraded from node 0.x to Node 5 which breaked my npm configuration . I uninstalled node deleted all npm regarding folders and reinstalled Node. If your OS cant find ```iron-node``` it is not path but it should automaticly. In fact this might impact other global modules in your machine?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the global **node_modules/bin** directory loaded inside the **PATH** variable. Otherwise the system doesn't know where to look for that executable